# Task Scheduler create task watcher

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Need to create a monitor/watcher which raise an event when task is created or modified in windows task scheduler.

Search a lot on how to monitor scheduled task create event but nothing found.

Please en-light me if I am searching something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be useful for your case: [MSDN TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_7). See the class "LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler " implementation.

It inherits the TaskScheduler, from which you have to implement some of its logic. It seems like it will expose the functionalities that you require.

Comment: If you need an example, I will attempt to create an implementation later today.